# How to unsubscribe in Angular by clicking button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to cancel a "device orientation" subscription in Angular using (click) in HTML. However for some reason it won't work. Anyone an idea for a solution?

**TS**

```
 // Watch the device compass heading change
  async watchOrientation() {

    var options = {
      frequency: 500,
    };

    this.orientation = this.deviceOrientation.watchHeading(options).subscribe( 
    (data: DeviceOrientationCompassHeading) => { this.orientation = data.magneticHeading.toFixed(2) },
    (error: any) => console.log(error)
    );
    console.log('watchOrientation button clicked')
  };

    // Stop watching heading change
    async stopOrientation() {
      this.orientation.unsubscribe()
      console.log('stopOrientation button clicked');
  };
```

**HTML**

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="pin" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>ion-item in a card, icon left, button right</ion-label>
      <ion-button fill="outline" slot="end" (click)="watchOrientation()" >Start</ion-button>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="pin" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>ion-item in a card, icon left, button right</ion-label>
      <ion-button color="danger" fill="outline" slot="end" (click)="stopOrientation()" >Stop</ion-button>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: What would you expect when you call `stopOrientation()` method ?

Comment: That the subscription stops. But I'm super new to TS & Angular. So could be very wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try:

instead of storing the subscription, try to add so that we won't lose it on any other assignment.

```
private subscription : Subscription = new Subscription();

// Watch the device compass heading change
  async watchOrientation() {

    var options = {
      frequency: 500,
    };

    this.subscription.add(this.deviceOrientation.watchHeading(options).subscribe( 
      (data: DeviceOrientationCompassHeading) => { this.orientation = data.magneticHeading.toFixed(2) },
      (error: any) => console.log(error)
    ));
    console.log('watchOrientation button clicked')
  };

    // Stop watching heading change
    async stopOrientation() {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      console.log('stopOrientation button clicked');
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately, this didn't work. Because "Subscription" is never used. Or did I get something wrong here?

Comment: in above code you should change `this.orientation` to `this.subscription`. I think is a typo from @Ganesh. and then in `stopOrientation` function add `this.subscription.unsubscribe()`

Comment: Now I get: this.subscription: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'

Comment: I'm guessing because you are doing: `this.orientation = data.magneticHeading.toFixed(2)` which isn't of type Subscription

Comment: How to do it then?

Comment: @Valentino initialize like `private orientation: Subscription = new Subscription();` and use the same to add and to unsubscribe().

Comment: @Ganesh could you please explain it in more detail. I'm still getting the same error as explained previously: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'

Comment: Now I got it working. Thanks a lot guy for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**JS**

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  orientation: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private deviceOrientation: DeviceOrientation,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
...
}

  }
  // Watch the device compass heading change
    watchOrientation() {

    var options = {
      frequency: 500,
    };

    this.subscription = this.deviceOrientation.watchHeading(options).subscribe( 
    (data: DeviceOrientationCompassHeading) => { this.orientation = data.magneticHeading.toFixed(2) },
    (error: any) => console.log(error)
    );
    console.log('button clicked')
    };
    
    stopOrientation() {
      // Stop watching heading change
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      console.log('stopOrientation()')
    };

}
```